DocuSign - ListStatusChangesOptions issue inside shared access user
We have a DocuSign Viewer account, and within the Viewer account, we have shared access users. How can we filter using from_date and custom_field with ListStatusChangesOptions.
I have already searched the internet but I can't find anything, can anyone help me.
